# Issue hiding a section Div Class

Tags: mobile, hide, liquid

I have tried following multiple guides on Stack Overflow however none seem to work on my website. The issue I am having is hiding the following code on mobile view only.

```
<div class="rte nice-paragraph">{{side_title[0]}}</div>
```

This is in a Shopify Liquid and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance/

Answer (score 0):

Please add following css code in the file

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
 .nice-paragraph {display:none;}
}
</style>
```

Thanks